# drawing shapes with SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

I've been looking around on internet for a tutorial how you install SDL_gfx in xcode for drawing shapes. Does anybody know any tutorials in how to set it up or where I can download it?

Answer (score 2):

http://lazyfoo.net/ is a great source for information on SDL.

Answer (score -1):

See 
[Ferzkopp SDL_gfx documentation](http://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL_gfx-2.0/Docs/html/index.html).
It has information about SDL_gfx and Xcode.